# Want to Delete file programmatically in App

Tags: java, android

I want to delete an apk file programmatically. In `onCreate` method I
want to implement a logic of checking if exists then delete as follows,

```
String location = Internal Storage\Downloads
if(location.myapplicaton.apk.isExists) {
  then delete myapplication.apk
} else {
  ....... 
}
```

Please give this solution with code example. And what kind of permission I want to include in Manifest and whatever the android version, it won't ask
user to delete or not.  It will directly delete this file. Thanks in
Advance guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done for obvious security reasons. An app can send an Intent to start another app and can send a request to access another apps data, but if there was a way for someone to program their app to delete other apps from somebody's phone without their permission it would be chaos.